# Screw positions in newer 3.5" hard drives do not match older case cage screw positions. Solution?

Tags: hard-drive, screws

I want to replace the old 3.5" hdd drive with a new drive but the mounting screw holes on all (?) of the newer  drives are in different positions that don't mount correctly.  Is there any sort of adapter that will let me mount the new 3.5" hdd in an older case with different mounting holes?

Comment: `on all (?) of the newer drives are in different positions`   .. please provide specific model information.  I personally doubt that this is true but I am also often wrong.

Comment: What sort of drive was in this tray/case previously, and what sort of drive are you trying to install? Are they both SATA or PATA, or SCSI, or do/did they have different connector types? Are you perhaps just turned around (just checking the simple, most likely things)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There's a whole lot of incredulity in comments here. How about the adage, "Just because *you* don't understand it does not make it unclear."

Answer (score 3):

This started with "larger than 4TB" drives that they changed the mount points. This was in 2014 just as everybody else was moving to smaller formats, 2.5", NVMe etc - which is I guess why people don't know about it.
Some are made with a 6-point mount which fits either system, others just 4 holes that won't fit anything you already own.

[Toshiba](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/eu/storage/support/faq/storage-holes.html) have the simplest pictorial explanation

[image]

but others such as WD have more in-depth info for the mechanically inclined. https://support.wdc.com/images/kb/2579-771970-A02.pdf

So - either you find a drive with 6 holes, or you see if someone makes an adapter or alternate sled mount.
OWC make them for the old Mac Pros, but I don't know about any other sellers.

> [image]

**One saving factor may be if your drive bays use the side screws - those haven't changed.**

Additionally, if your mounts are the other way up to the ones on the Mac Pro, ie 'screw side down' then you could probably get away with just two screws on a desktop, not subject to a great deal of physical handling. I have smaller 2.5" SSDs that literally just rest in place, because gravity does the work & the machines don't do a lot of travelling.

Comment: I've been confounded recently by this - being a late adopter and frugal bastard im just now buying a hard disk >6TB and teying to fit it into my decade old Cooler Master N400 case, which unfortunately only has holes for the middle and bottom screws on the old hdd design, so i can only get 1 screw into each large capacity hdd. I have scoured the interwebs for solutions and can't find it. So so I think i'm gonna be tapping some holes into sheet metal soon.. :(